# How do I send strings of data to a SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, string, visual-studio, parameters

I have created a simple Username and Password login form in visual studio using c# which works great I then coded it so that whatever Username and Password was entered into the two textboxes was saved as a string... Now I want to pass those strings as parameters and store them into an SQL query... Any idea how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Well, why don't ask google for something like "c# sql server parameterized query" first, then try to implement it according to examlples you'll found, and then (if you've stuck with something) - post your question at SO....

Comment: There are probably more examples of C# SQL code on the internet than there is porn. It shouldn't be hard to find what you want with a simple search!

Comment: Trust me there isnt!

Comment: You'll also want to do a search on "salted hashed passwords" as well - you should not be storing passwords plain-text :)

Comment: Oh no don't worry the passwords aren't going to be stored in plain text, I've created a code which applies an encryption key to the password to completely mask the original

Comment: [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [two](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/837599/Using-Csharp-to-connect-to-and-query-from-a-SQL-da), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709305/how-to-directly-execute-sql-query-in-c-have-example-batch-file), [four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735531/sql-c-best-method-for-executing-a-query), [five](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter), [six](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/05/28/how-to-query-a-database-in-csharp/)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend **NOT** to store passwords as plain text. Instead look into hashed password methods.

Firstly you will need to specify a connection string. This can be done in the `config` file as:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=ServerAddress;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Now you want to read the connection string from your `config` file and you can do that in your C# code as:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

I'm assuming you'll be inserting records. If you are going to update records, then you will need to change the query. For inserting records:

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO MyTable (UserNameColumn,PasswordColumn) VALUES (@UserName, @Password)";
```

Finally to execute the query and pass our parameters we can do

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, connection))
   {
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UserNameTextBox.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PasswordTextBox.Text;

     connection.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Dont forget to include the namespace `using System.Configuration;`

Comment: It is better to be `SqlDbType.NVarChar`.

Comment: @musefan I started programming for the first time on Monday... when I started  my new job... this is my 5th day programming I don't think you have the right to call anyone an Idiot to be honest and I doubt anyone will listen to your answer if you just insult people. I have my full Cisco server engineer qualification... I'd like to see you wire, set-up and manage a server built through out a 40 thousand capacity stadium you "Idiot"

Comment: @musefan I'd rather take longer to make this answer decent then to have a conversation with you.

Comment: @yawn... answer is still not improved...

Comment: @musefan are you still here?

Comment: @musefan Have a look, anything I missed?

Comment: @Izzy: Looks good to me ;)

Comment: @Izzy thank you for all the help! its very appreciated

Comment: @DeclanTiff You're welcome.. Glad I could help