# C# return value of a 'SELECT' query

Tags: c#, oledb

My connection string:

```
string connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
    @"Data Source=\\reso-fs-2\allusers\Student_Home\20350657\Documents\clicker.accdb;" +
    @"Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + "password" + ";";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection);
```

So I have this query in C# OleDb:

```
string query = "SELECT stats_best FROM Users WHERE username="+GameForm.username;
```

I want to fetch the value from 'stats_best' and save it into a string.
I have already set-up the connection and all that. I just need to return a value from the query.
How can I do that?

Comment: Did you read anything about creating and executing a command? Please take some tutorials since this is the wrong way to learn...

Comment: [How to: Create and Execute an SQL Statement that Returns Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx)

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21709663/993547.

Comment: I tried executing commands but every time I get an exception that one of the variables is missing in runtime but everything is there. I looked into it and can't find a solution.

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3735547/993547.

Comment: I don't want to return a row, I already know how to do that. I need to return a single value and save it into a string.

Comment: So what is the exception? What is the actual SQL statement executed?

Comment: I execute a OleDbCommand using OleDbDataReader and read the first value from the reader. I get the 'No value given for one or more required parameters.' exception on runtime.

Comment: So `GameForm.usename` might be null?

Comment: GameForm.username has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Please Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx) article, but anyway, you can use this

```
public string Test(string userName, string connectionString, out string dbErrorMessage)
    {
        string result = null;
        dbErrorMessage = null;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", userName));
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT stats_best FROM Users WHERE username= @UserName";
                result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dbErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and the usage of method:

```
string dbErrorMessage = null;
Test(GameForm.username, connectionString, out dbErrorMessage);
```

Comment: This seems to execute but it doesn't return the value from the database.

Comment: did you check your `ConnectionString`?

Comment: I can't check your connection string from here, please check if it works. And what is result of execution?

Comment: The program executes but doesn't return a value. Maybe it's because i'm using OleDbConnection rather than SqlConnection. Could this method be adapted to OleDbConnection?

Comment: `"Data Source=\\reso-fs-2\allusers\Student_Home\20350657\Documents\clicker.accdb;Initial Catalog=<enter database Name>;User=<UserName>;Password=<password>;"`, something like this

Comment: Nothing seems to be returning the string. Thank you for your help though.