# Parsing a text file upon upload in .NET

Tags: sql, .net, parsing

I have a web-project where I need to:

1.Browse for a file and upload
2. Parse file at the semicolon
3. Submit file to the server

The files that are being uploaded are .sql files where each SQL statement ends in a semicolon (;).  The idea would be to parse 1 SQL statement per row. (The source file could have SQL statements that span 20 rows, but the semicolon at line 20 means that statement goes into one row.

This is all new to me for the most part, but what I have so far is a button that searches for a file, and stores it to my local drive.  I will worry about the exact storage location later, but I am interested now in how to parse the .sql files as described above.  Any ideas where to start to incorporate this into my code?

Thanks

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="FileUpload.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <%-- <form id="form1" runat="server"> --%> 
        <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace FileUpload
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the file (File.ReadAllText) split the returned string at semicolon (string.Split), work on the string array returned where each element is your 'single row'

Answer (score 0):

After upload file open it as text file and parse each line or ';' as sql command.
Open file
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx

Excute sql query

[SQL/C# - Best method for executing a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735531/sql-c-best-method-for-executing-a-query)