# Displaying Data from database based on value from datetimepicker

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I have a billing Details Table which contains all details of sale. I have a bill date column which gets value from datetimepicker. The bill date column is of type datetime. I want to display data based on a date from datetimepicker. I am trying to get details by using value changed event of datetime picker. But i cant get values.

below is my code,

```
 DateTime Date = dateTimePicker_CustomerCustomerReports.Value;
                string CS = "data source=.; database=BillingSoftware; user id=sa; Password=9495640";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT 
                                                            Bill_Date as [Bill Date],
                                                            Name,
                                                            Item,
                                                            Item_Code as [Item Code],
                                                            MRP, 
                                                            Quantity,
                                                            Amount as Total, 
                                                            Amount_After_Discount as [Grand Total]  
                                                        From POS  LEFT JOIN Customers 
                                                        ON POS.Customer=Customers.Customer_Id 
                                                        WHERE Customer_Id>=1 
                                                        AND Bill_Date Like @BillDate 
                                                        Order by Name", con);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillDate", Date);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dgv_CustomerCustomerReport.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Have you checked whether dt gets any data after filling or not, if not then check your query.

Comment: The code doesn't returns values or value change event is not fired?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735531/sql-c-best-method-for-executing-a-query

Comment: Im getting no error. The POS table has values. the change event is not firing? I dont knw why its not working!

Comment: just check if event is bound properly.

Comment: How to check that?