# How to retrieve desired date from access database using C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm working on access database using C#, want an SQL statement to select all information based on a desired date. for example today.

```
"SELECT * from mytable where mytable.dates == DateTime.Today()";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL/C# - Best method for executing a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735531/sql-c-best-method-for-executing-a-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question right and you want to make a call to the SQL Server, you can use `SQLCommand` and parameters.

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from mytable where mytable.dates= @DateAdded";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", DateTime.Today);
```